# What does the vertex/focus/directrix of a conic correspond to in projective space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

A conic section can be viewed as the preimage of a circle in two dimensional projective-space.

Take a polynomial $p(x, y)$ in $\mathbb{R}[x, y]$, of degree $2$. Write $p(x, y) = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + d x + ey + f$. The embedding of varieties $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{RP}^3$ sending $(x, y)$ to $[(x, y, 1)]$ has $f^{-1} (V(Q)) = V(p)$, where $Q (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3[x, y, z]$ is the degree $3$ polynomial which is the `homogenization' of $p$, $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dxz + eyz + fz^2$. $Q$ is a quadratic form, so there is a symmetric linear map $A : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $Q(v) = v^* Av$ for $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$. By a general formula, we have
$$ A = \left[ \begin{matrix}a & b/2 & c/2  \\ 
b/2 & c & e/2 \\ 
c/2 & e/2 & f  \end{matrix} \right]$$

We would like to switch $Q$ for $Q \circ \Phi$ where $\Phi$ is an isomorphism chosen so that $Q \circ \Phi$ has a nice form. This swaps $\Phi^* A \Phi$ for $A$.

Using only orthogonal matrices $\Phi$, we can put $A$
 in the form $$\left[ \begin{matrix}r & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & s & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & t  \end{matrix} \right] $$

Then, using certain diagonal matrices, we can make $A$ into a diagonal matrix with only $0$, $1$, and $-1$ in the collumns, all of which give quadratic forms whose zero-sets are simple to visualize. See [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) for more on this point. Note that, over $\mathbb{C}$, we could get a diagonal matrix with only $0$'s and $1$'s in the diagonal.

> **Question:** What is an interpretation of the following invariants of conic sections under this point of view?
>
> 1) The vertex of the conic section.
>
> 2) The foci of the conic section.
>
> 3) The directrix of the conic section.

To be clear, I am asking what the vertex of the conic section corresponds to in projective space as an invariant of a projective circle, and the same for (2) and (3).